# How to stop occurrence of same device again and again

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android app that scans and listable device in a TextView . I'm not getting how to remove occurrence of same device again and again.

Below is the code i'm scanning devices. What amendments to make here?

```
private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        t_c.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName()
            + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n");
    }

};
```

Comment: Maintain a Set<> probably.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao  tried to maintain a list but that didn't work either. 
I'm an absolute noob to android.

Comment: List allows duplicate, Set does not. Before you append just check if data already in Set. `if(devicSet.contains(device))`.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Thank you so much my problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for others.

The scan returning a device each time it finds one. There can be echo, same device found twice. OP wants to display only unique devices.

Solution:
Maintain a `Set` of Devices. Set data structure does not allow duplicate and solves the problem.

Once a new device is found add to deviceSet. Before adding check if device already exists. `if(devicSet.contains(device))`. If device already exists no-need to append to display.